# Vb.net Excel move to next row

Tags: vb.net, excel, office-interop, excel-interop, vba

Hey all I am looking to see how to go about moving 1 row over where I am currently in my spreadsheet.

I have tried:

```
Dim xlsApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlsWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlsCell As Excel.Range

xlsCell = xlsSheet.Range("A1", "A100")

For Each oRowRange As Excel.Range In xlsCell.Rows
    For Each oCellRange As Excel.Range In oRowRange.Columns

      If colorRGB = "252, 213, 180" Then
         Debug.WriteLine(oCellRange.Text)
         oCellRange.Offset(0, 1).Select()
         Debug.WriteLine(oCellRange.Text)
         etc...
      End If
    Next
Next
```

In the example above, it keeps putting the same text:

> BOB
>
> BOB

When it really should be:

> BOB
>
> JON

So any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is that you use the same line twice `Debug.WriteLine(oCellRange.Text)`. After the first one, the `oCellRange` isn't changed. You're using `.Select`, kind of.  You do `.Select`, but then never use `Selection`...this is a [good thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).  However, just tweak that second line and remove the `.Select` line:

```
     Debug.WriteLine(oCellRange.Text)
     Debug.WriteLine(oCellRange.Offset(0, 1).Text)
```

Edit: Alternatively, you could replace the `.Select` line with `Set oCellRange = oCellRange.Offset(0,1)` and leave that third line as is.  However, I don't suggest this and would personally keep the `.Offset()` method.

Comment: That got it. Thanks Bruce!

Comment: @StealthRT - Of course, you could alternatively reset `oCell` after that first line and do what I showed in my edit.